# Need assistance to: write a small program that will turn on the computer and executes a specified program.

Tags: c#

I need to write a small program, to set a timer that turns on system, and run a program.
I know how to run a program, but the problem is how to turn on system and windows?

Comment: Do you want to know how to wake the local computer, or a different computer on the network?

Answer (score 7):

Use [Lego Mindstorms](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/Default.aspx) to build a robot that will push the power button of your computer  to turn it on after specific time interval.

Comment: I would have said wake on lan like the others have but this idea is a lot better :)

Comment: This might very well be a humorous answer. And although the question might be simple (and poorly formulated) and easily googleable, this isn't really a useful answer. It might have been appropriate and amusing as a comment, but as a separate answer not so in my opinion. And it for certain doesn't deserve all these upvotes! Just my two cents...

Answer (score 4):

To turn a system on you should use Wake On LAN: [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/cswol.aspx) you can find an example written in C#

Answer (score 1):

If target computer BIOS supports [Wake-Over-LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) feature this can be done via sending network packet to a remote computer, which you need to wake up. But you need at least 2 computers. One - target, that needs to be started, and one - with your application, that tracks time and sends network packet to target computer.